# Скрывается popover если часто изменять значение формы

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем привет.
У меня есть форма с фильтрами. При изменении значений хочу вывести popover с кнопкой "Перейти" которая скрывается через 4 секунды. Проблема проявляется если изменять значения формы чаще чем в 4 секунды. Старый popover исчезает, на долю секунды появляется новый и сразу же исчезает.

Вот мой код:

```
function debounce(func, wait, immediate) {
    var timeout;
    return function() {
        var context = this, args = arguments;
        var later = function() {
            timeout = null;
            if (!immediate) func.apply(context, args);
        };
        var callNow = immediate && !timeout;
        clearTimeout(timeout);
        timeout = setTimeout(later, wait);
        if (callNow) func.apply(context, args);
    };
};


$('.filter__entity input, .filter__entity select').on('change keypress keydown', debounce(
    function(){
        //$('.filter__entity').popover('hide');
        $filterForm = $('*[data-role=filter-form]');
        action = $filterForm.attr('action');
        data = $filterForm.serialize();
        console.log(data);
        $(this).parents('.filter__entity').popover('destroy');
        $(this).parents('.filter__entity').popover({
            'content': '<a href="' + action + '?' + data + '" class="filter__submit button" style="margin: 1em;">Подобрать</a>',
            'html': true,
            'delay': { 'show': 300, 'hide': 100, },
        }).popover('show');

        // autohiding
        $('.filter__entity').on('shown.bs.popover', function() {
            var $pop = $(this);
            setTimeout(function () {
                $pop.popover('hide');
            }, 4000);
        });
    }, 300)
);
```

Полагаю, что виной тому autohiding, который срабатывает для второго popover, хотя должен был сработать для первого.
Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Код не из простых, скажем прямо.Я не смог заставить `popover` всегда адекватно реагировать на `.filter__entity select` `change`: почему-то иногда при смене значения `popover` появляется и сразу исчезает. Хотя код как в вопросе (только `$(this).parents('.filter__entity')` вынесено в переменную). [Проблемный fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oysb78Lt/1/).

Comment: В частности, не срабатывает `shown.bs.popover` для `.filterEntity`.

Comment: Из-за этой проблемы протестировать топорное решение (с помощью счетчика) проблемы и не получается: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/oysb78Lt/2/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть подозрение, что для нового события срабатывает старый таймаут.
Надо присвоить ему глобальный `id` и в `shown.bs.popover` всегда отменять старые таймауты.
[Как то так](https://jsfiddle.net/f9af9h3k/)
`<input type="text" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="down" data-content="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus." data-trigger="focus">`
js
`$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('change keypress keydown',function(){
    $(this).popover('show');
});
var timeout;
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    t = $(this);
    clearTimeout(timeout);
    timeout = setTimeout(function(){
       t.popover('hide');
    },4000);
});`

Comment: добавьте, пожалуйста, код с jsfiddle непосредственно в тело ответа (ссылку убирать не надо).

Comment: Вау! Это работает! Осталось  понять почему... Ведь при открытии popover вызывается clearTimeout. Он должен убивать функцию скрытия.

Comment: Я же объяснил, что для нового события срабатывает таймаут предыдущего события или может быть еще более раннего.

Comment: Всё, теперь понял. Сам поповер убивался в одном месте (при повторном вызове, а setTimeout оставался ждать)... И убивал новый открывшийся... Спасибо вам